# InteractiveScene3DEvent not firing in Papervision BasicView

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d

I'm using BasicView to setup my PV3D scene, and the scene itself works fine (3d carousel of movie posters) but the InteractiveScene3DEvent is not firing when a poster is clicked or moused over.

I set my viewport to interactive... twice.

```
view = new BasicView(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,true);
view.viewport.buttonMode = true;
view.viewport.interactive = true;
```

And here is the part of the loop where it the event listener is added.

```
var mm:filmsPoster = new filmsPoster();
mm.loadIMG(image);

var mat:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial(mm);
mat.interactive = true;
mat.animated = true;
mat.smooth = true;
mat.doubleSided = true;
mat.name = filmName;
mat.addEventListener(InteractiveScene3DEvent.OBJECT_CLICK, posterClick);
```

Comment: there is no display object potentially in front of the material?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to listen to the object which you give the MovieMaterial, like :

```
var plane : Plane = new Plane(mat, 700, 700, 3, 3);
plane.addEventListener(InteractiveScene3DEvent.OBJECT_CLICK, posterClick);
```